# PHP mysqli не могу вывести данные

Tags: php, база-данных, mysqli

Есть класс php в котором 2 метода, 1ый для соединения с БД, 2ой для запроса и помещения данных в массив, не могу вывести этот массив в другом коде, не пойму в каком методе проблема, правильный ли подход к задаче?

```
class DataAccess{
    private $DB_HOSTNAME = 'local';
    private $USERNAME = 'user';
    private $PASSWORD = 'pass';
    private $DB_NAME = 'db_name';
    private $mysqli;

    public function connect_db() {
        $this -> mysqli = new mysqli($DB_HOSTNAME, $USERNAME, $PASSWORD, $DB_NAME);
        if($this -> mysqli)
            echo "Connection succesful";
        else 
            die ("Problem with connection" . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    public function getAll() {
        $sqlQuery = 'SELECT COUNT(pay) FROM payment';
        $result = $this -> mysqli -> query($sqlQuery);
        return $result;
    }
}
```

файл в котором хочу вывести

```
require 'DataAccess.php';

$test = new DataAccess();
$test -> connect_db();

$result = $test -> getAll();
echo $result;
```

Comment: дак getAll() должен что-то возвращать тогда, а не просто через echo выплевывать... где вы этот нужный массив формируете, чтобы он в $result ушел?

Comment: Почему вы к свойствам класса внутри класса обращаетесь как к переменным?

Comment: Изменил код, правил код здесь, ничего не помогло, помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во первых включите отчеты об ошибках

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

и не `mysqli($DB_HOSTNAME, $USERNAME, $PASSWORD, $DB_NAME);`

а `mysqli($this->DB_HOSTNAME, $this->USERNAME, $this->PASSWORD, $this->DB_NAME);`

и массив в конце выводите `print_r($result);` а не echo

P.S.

а реквизиты подключения к базе можно сделать константами.